# Verify order of convergence of the Euler--Maruyama schemenumerically

Tags: numerical-methods, stochastic-differential-equations, eulers-method

I have a question about the order of convergence of the Euler-Maruyama scheme and how one verifes this numerically.

I have read that the Euler-Maruyama scheme is mean-squared convergent of order 1/2 where (I think) mean-square convergence is defined by:

$$
\max_{n=1\dots N} \lVert X(t_n) -Y_n \rVert_{L_2}  \leq C h^{1/2}, 
$$
where $ \lVert Z \rVert_{L_2} = \left( \mathbb{E}|Z|^2\right)^{1/2}$, $X(t_n)$ is the solution to an SDE at timepoint $t_n$ and $Y_n$ is the Euler-Maruyama approximation at $t_n$.

I want to verify this numerically and my approach is to approximate the norm with a monte-carlo simulation by simulating $M$ sample paths and computing

$$
\lVert X(t_n) -Y_n \rVert_{L_2}  \approx \left( \frac{1}{M} \sum_{j=1}^M |X^j(t_n) -Y^j_n|^2 \right)^{1/2}
$$

($j$ is the number of the simulated sample path) and for a sequence of different grids and for each grid take the maximum. Instead of using the true solution to the SDE I calculate the Euler-Maruyama solution on a very fine grid and use this as the reference solution.
I then simulate the EM-approximation on coarser grids (but using the driver process that I used for the reference solution). This however gives me strange results (the convergence plot doesn't indicate any convergence).

It seems to work (I get order of convergence $1/2$) if I instead take the $|X^j(T) - Y^j_N|$ (the absolute value of the difference at the end point for each sampel path $j$) and then take the avergage of these for each grid.  My question is if I have misunderstood something or my approach is incorrect?

Thank you and kind regards,

Comment: Where are you taking the maximum here: $
\lVert X(t_n) -Y_n \rVert_{L_2}  \approx \left( \frac{1}{M} \sum_{j=1}^M |X^j(t_n) -Y^j_n|^2 \right)^{1/2}
$ ?

Comment: That's before the maximum is taken. You compute that for each time point t_n and then you' take the maximum over n (if I understood it correctly).

Comment: I think this formula: $\max_{n=1\dots N} \lVert X(t_n) -Y_n \rVert_{L_2}  \leq C h^{1/2}$  is incorrect. I think you have to take the maximum before and then take the expected value. Did you get that formula from a book?

Comment: In other words, I think you should take the maximum for each path and then compute the expectation.

Comment: Thanks for you input! So you're saying the estimate should be $\left(\frac{1}{M} \sum_{j=1}^M \max{n =1, \dots} | X^j(t_n) -Y^j_n|^2 \right^{1/2}$?  I've the form above in my post in several lecture notes but perhaps this is wrong...

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I actually don't get it to work but perhaps there's an issue with my code then.